# Pandas df, combine rows based values in 4 columns with Nans, take max()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, None, None],
    'col2': [None, None, 1, 2],
    'col3': ['a', 'b', None, None],
    'col4': [None, None, 'a', 'c'],
    'col5': ['2022-04-01', '2022-05-01', None, None],
    'col6': [None, None, '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01']
})
   col1  col2  col3  col4        col5        col6
0   1.0   NaN     a  None  2022-04-01        None
1   2.0   NaN     b  None  2022-05-01        None
2   NaN   1.0  None     a        None  2022-06-01
3   NaN   2.0  None     c        None  2022-07-01
```

I would like to merge the rows based on col1:col4, where col1=col2 and col3=col4. And then take only max value in col 5 and col 6. So the result should look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4        col5        col6
0   1.0   1.0     a     a  2022-04-01  2022-06-01
1   2.0   NaN     b  None  2022-05-01        None
2   NaN   2.0  None     c        None  2022-07-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom grouper:

```
g = df[['col1', 'col3']].combine_first(df[['col2', 'col4']].set_axis(['col1','col3'],axis=1))

out = df.groupby(g.apply(tuple, axis=1), as_index=False).first()

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4        col5        col6
0   1.0   1.0     a     a  2022-04-01  2022-06-01
1   2.0   NaN     b  None  2022-05-01        None
2   NaN   2.0  None     c        None  2022-07-01
```